# How to get Node.js library support in Sublimt Text 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, webstorm

I've tried many ST3 plugins, but many of them are not well-documented, or have rather out-dated documentation. Also, very quickly I find Sublime plugins could <s>randomly</s> crashed amongst each other...

So I ended up with some of the common one like:

- SublimeCodeIntel
- SublimeLinter - JShint
- JavaScriptNext

*Sublime Coding Interface*
[image]

## But.

I've been using **WebStorm 9** that can auto-suggest (*thus auto-complete*) while doing JavaScript.

Is there any way to get **Sublime Text 3** to auto-complete Node.js, specifically:

*WebStorm Coding Interface*
[image: WebStorm Interface]

Answer (score 0):

I used to write Javascript in Sublime Text. But I think my experience still applies to ST2/3. The plugins you use are probably too weak to provide you true semantic completion suggestion. `JShint` is a linting tool, anyway. `JSNext` just provides next version JavaScript, namely es6, syntax and keywords. So the suggestions you get are, after all, a list of text that appears either in your own files or in JS syntax.

Fortunately, there is ST plugins that give you IDE like intelligent completion. [TernJS](http://ternjs.net/) is one of the best I think, and it has [ST port plugin](https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-tern).

[image]

Even in a old text editor you can get amazing completion, as long as a decent plugin is installed.